# how to use cocosbuilder when developing android using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, cocosbuilder

I am developing an app on Android platform based on cocos2d-x. I used cocosbuild to design the scene and published the ccbi file. But where should I put the ccbi file and how to use this in  eclipse？